# how to retrive the blob image

Tags: c#, mysql, blob

i have written a code but its not working properly.first i a trying to make a folder and store  the image there but as my database is hosted it creating a problem so i store the image as a blob.kindly help me out where i am doing the mistake. thanks.

```
public void ItemList_with_images(string value)
{
  flowLayoutPanelItemList.Controls.Clear();
  //  string img_directory = Application.StartupPath + @"\ITEMIMAGE\";
  // string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(img_directory, "*.png *.jpg");
  try
  {
    conn.Open();

    string sql = 
      "select distinct Item.Item_id,Item.name,Item.image,Item.cost,Item.price, Category.Name as cat_name from  Item" +
      " INNER JOIN Category ON Item.Category_id=Category.Category_id" +
      " INNER JOIN Ingredients ON Item.Item_id=Ingredients.item_id" +
      " INNER JOIN Inventory ON Inventory.Inventory_id = Ingredients.invenotry_id" +
      " INNER JOIN inventory_detail ON inventory_detail.inventory_id = Inventory.Inventory_id" +
      " where(Item.name like '" + value + "%'  and inventory_detail.Quantity > 0 and inventory_detail.loc_id =" + UserInfo.Loc_id + ") " +
      "OR (Category.Name like '" + value + "%'  and inventory_detail.Quantity > 0 and inventory_detail.loc_id =" + UserInfo.Loc_id + ") ";

    dataexe.ExecuteSQL(sql, conn);
    DataTable dt = dataexe.GetDataTable(sql, conn);

    int currentImage = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
      DataRow dataReader = dt.Rows[i];

      Button b = new Button();
      //Image i = Image.FromFile(img_directory + dataReader["name"]);
      b.Tag = dataReader["Item_id"];
      b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);



      string details = dataReader["Item_id"] +
        "\n Name: " + dataReader["name"].ToString() +
        "\n Buy price: " + dataReader["cost"].ToString() +
        "\n Sell price: " + dataReader["price"].ToString();

      b.Name = details;


      ImageList il = new ImageList();
      il.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
      il.TransparentColor = Color.Transparent;
      il.ImageSize = new Size(78, 80);
      // here i am getting error
      il.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream((byte[]) dataReader["image"])));
      //  il.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(img_directory + dataReader["image"]));


      b.Image = il.Images[0];
      b.Margin = new Padding(3, 3, 3, 3);

      b.Size = new Size(208, 100);
      b.Text.PadRight(4);

      b.Text += dataReader["name"].ToString();

      b.Text += "\n Price: " + dataReader["price"];

      b.Font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
      b.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
      b.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
      flowLayoutPanelItemList.Controls.Add(b);
      currentImage++;

    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

''''

[images are not retriving correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYr2h.png)

Comment: you should add more details, what's wrong? what have you tried to resolve it? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: can you please try breaking up the line where you are getting the error? ie: `var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[]) dataReader["image"])`, etc

Comment: @ShaiCohen when i am trying to add image its actually not giving the error but images are not retriving correctly . you can see SS attached

Comment: i realize you are new to SO, and that's fine. In order to not have the community spend time needlessly, can you please post the *full* code. Also, please invest the time in formatting your code as well. Thank you!

Comment: @ShaiCohen plz check in 3 min

Comment: @ShaiCohen plz check

Comment: please show the DDL for the table you are selecting from.

Comment: Fairly sure the issue is you are not specifying the size of the memory stream when you create it -- you probably need to do it on a new line to be able to specify the size.  cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/32184992/215752

Comment: @Hogan - I'm not sure that's the case, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Side note: using `distinct` with an `image` or `varbinary(max)` column in the projection is a big red flag.

Comment: @madreflection - one of many red flags unfortunately.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using an `ImageList`, if there *is* a reason please let me know. That being said, here is a very short (and tested) method which loads an image from a file and assigns it to a button's `Image` property. Below it is an adaptation of the first method, using the `datareader` as per your code. *this method has **not** been tested*.

```
    public void GetImage()
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Shai Cohen\Pictures\banana.jpg"));
        Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        button1.Image = image;
    }

    public void GetImageFromDatareader()
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream((byte[]) dataReader["image"]));
        Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
        button1.Image = image;
    }
```

Comment: i have placed the images in the table as a blob. i am trying to make the POS that why i am using imageList

Comment: what is POS? Also, you are creating a new `ImageList` for each image: is this what you intended?

Comment: POS (Point Of Sale)